# How can I build custom xticklabels using numbers and strings?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis, xticks

I am trying to customize the `Xticklabels` of my bar graph to have a format of 'number (units)'

So far I have a vector:

```
scanrate = [2;4;6;8;10];
```

I want my bar graph to have an x axis of:

```
2mv/s 4mv/s 6mv/s 8mv/s 10mv/s
```

If I use `xticklabels(num2str(scanrate))`
the `xticklabels` change to the numbers in the `scanrate` vector. I want to put mv/s after each Xtick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) :

```
xticklabels(strcat(num2str(scanrate),' mv/s'))
```

Please note that it works only when `scanrate` is a column vector.

---

Fun fact :

```
num2str(scanrate) + " mv/s"
```

also works, but

```
num2str(scanrate) + ' mv/s'
```

does not

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the "fun fact" case works because it's a `string` rather than `char` operation, and `"` and `'` are very much _expected_ to have different behaviour

Comment: Yes worth noting indeed. I put it in the answer because it might make relatively new MATLAB users go and check the differences between `string` and `char` out of curiosity

Answer (score 4):

Build your strings using [`sprintf()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), where the `%d` flag is for an unsigned integer:

```matlab
my_labels = {};
for ii = 1:numel(scanrate)
    my_labels{ii} = sprintf('%dmv/s', scanrate(ii));
end

figure;
% (...) make your plot
xticklabels(my_labels)
```

Alternative one-liner, thanks to [Wolfie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077854/how-can-i-build-custom-xticklabels-using-numbers-and-strings/73078153#comment129068206_73078153):

```
my_labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%dmv/s',x),scanrate,'uni',0);
```

As a side note: that's normally not what you'd do when creating these type of plots. You'd just have numbers on the axes and a label stating something as "Velocity [mv/s]", rather than having the unit on every single tick label.

Comment: This can be disguised/condensed using `my_labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%dmv/s',x),scanrate,'uni',0);` to much the same effect